# Python patched Class - method return_value returns MagicMock

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-mock

I have a function that determines if a token can be pulled from environment variables, or from Google Cloud Secret Manager (via a custom class).

I am mocking the secret manager connection class so it doesn't actually connect to GCP, however the `pull_secret()` method I have from it is returning another MagicMock object.

Here's the function code (`utility_functions.py`):

```
def fetch_token(secret_name: str):
try:
    token = os.environ['TOKEN']
except KeyError:
    print("TOKEN environment variable not set. Pulling Secret from Google Cloud Secret Manager...")
    token = None

if token is None or token == '':
    gcp_sm = SecretManagerConnection()
    token = gcp_sm.pull_secret(project_id=os.environ['GCP_PROJECT_ID'], secret_name=secret_name)

return token
```

The test code I am using is as follows:

```py
@patch("app.utilities.utility_functions.SecretManagerConnection")
def test_fetch_token_google_secret(mock_sm):
    os.environ["GCP_PROJECT_ID"] = "test"

    mock_sm.pull_secret().return_value = "1234567890.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    del os.environ["TOKEN"]

    assert fetch_token("test") == "1234567890.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

The Error I get is `AssertionError: assert <MagicMock name='SecretManagerConnection().pull_secret()' id='2533589158400'> == '1234567890.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`

Is there something I am doing wrong in trying to assign the `pull_secret()` return value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Cause of the problem

Patching `SecretManagerConnection` class will replace it with a magic mock instance. When this class is instantiated in the `fetch_token` function, the instantiated class will return the `return_value` of mock instance which in your case is not properly configured/set.

### How to fix this?

Configure/set the `return_value` for `pull_secret` method on the `return_value` of mocked class rather than setting on the mocked class itself.

```
@patch("app.utilities.utility_functions.SecretManagerConnection")
def test_fetch_token_google_secret(mock_sm):
    os.environ["GCP_PROJECT_ID"] = "test"

    instance = mock_sm.return_value
    instance.pull_secret.return_value = "1234567890.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    del os.environ["TOKEN"]
    assert fetch_token("test") == "1234567890.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

Comment: Thanks. For completeness for anyone else reading, I also noticed that I was trying to assign the return value to the callable `pull_secret()`, instead of just `pull_secret`.